# on mountain vs at mountain

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

> Now we were *on/at* Mt. Fuji, climbing up and up.

What would be the difference between choosing *on* or *at* here?

Answer (score 1):

"At" refers to the general location of something, *including the area right around it*. So if you are "at the school", you might be in the parking lot across the street from it.

Other prepositions, including "on", are more precise.

So if you're at Mt. Fuji, you could be somewhere near the base. But if you're "on" Mt. Fuji, it necessarily means you're somewhere on the mountain itself.